# Pasting a date with single quotation marks

Tags: r, paste

I currently have a function written out, but for the sake of simplicity, I'll just post an altered version:

```
i = '2018-08-05'


s = paste("SELECT
          *
          FROM table.a 
          WHERE event_date = DATE(", paste(i, collapse = " "), ")
          LIMIT 10;
          ;", sep = '')
```

As it stands, it would currently produce an output that looks like:

```
WHERE event_date = DATE(2018-08-05)
```

I need it to look like:

```
WHERE event_date = DATE('2018-08-05')
```

EDIT: Now that the initial problem is fixed, I'm running into an issue for how R is reading the date format:

```
dates <- seq.Date(from = as.Date('2018-07-01'), to = Sys.Date(), by = 1)
  for(i in dates){
    s = paste("SELECT
          *
              FROM table.a 
              WHERE event_date = DATE(", paste(i, collapse = " "), ")
              LIMIT 10;
              ;", sep = '')


  results_query <- dbGetQuery(con,  s)

}
```

Is returning a format that looks like `WHERE event_date = DATE(17713)`

Answer (score 1):

Add double quotes around your `i` to preserve the single quotes:

```
i = "'2018-08-05'"

s = paste0("SELECT
          *
          FROM table.a 
          WHERE event_date = DATE(", i, ")
          LIMIT 10;
          ;")
```

**Output:**

```
> cat(s)
SELECT
          *
          FROM table.a 
          WHERE event_date = DATE('2018-08-05')
          LIMIT 10;
          ;
```

**Edit** -- I would suggest trying out @G. Grothendieck's solution, but here is how I would do it using a `for` loop:

```
dates <- seq.Date(from = as.Date('2018-07-01'), to = Sys.Date(), by = 1)

for(i in seq_along(dates)){
  s = paste0("SELECT
            *
            FROM table.a 
            WHERE event_date = DATE('", dates[i], "')
            LIMIT 10;
            ;")
  results_query <- dbGetQuery(con,  s)
}
```

Comment: Oh, duh. I feel very stupid for not remembering to do that!

Comment: @gooponyagrinch we all feel dumb from time to time :)

Comment: Thanks! I added an edit for another problem I'm running into and perhaps you can help

Answer (score 1):

**1)** The gsubfn package includes a function `fn$` that when prefaced to any other function will scan its arguments and perform string interpolation.  If you are using the sqldf package then gsubfn is already loaded automatically or if not you can use `library`.  Preface the variable name with $ to have its value substituted into the string.

```
library(gsubfn)

sql <- fn$identity(
  "SELECT *
   FROM event_date = DATE('$i')
   LIMIT 10"
)
```

or you can preface whatever function you are using to send the string to the database with `fn$` instead of using `identity`.

**2)** A base only solution would be to use sprintf:

```
fmt <- 
  "SELECT *
   FROM event_date = DATE('%s')
   LIMIT 10"
sql <- sprintf(fmt, i)
```

Comment: @ G. Grothendieck - Thanks! Would you be able to help with my edit that I added?

Comment: Just set `datesi <- dates[i]` and then use `$datesi` in (1) in place of `$i`.  In (2) just use `dates[i]` in place of `i` in the `sprintf` statement.  Alternately in (1) you can put `dates[i]` in backquotes in place of `$i` in the sql string.  Anything within backquotes will be executed by R and the entire backquoted portion replaced with the reslt.